# Android xhdpi density and resolution

Tags: android, layout, screen, resolution

I'm a bit confused and i hope you can help me. I'm developing an application for smartphones and i'm using prefixes like: `mdpi`, `hdpi` and `xhpi`. With first two i don't have any problems.

According to this:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
- and this
  http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

`xhdpi` is 640x960 px screen size and I have prepared my graphics for this resolution. But I can't find any device with this resolution. Instead of this, in android layout editor I have, for example, Galaxy Nexus which is marked as `xhdpi` device, but it has 720p screen size.

So my question is, I should look at this tables from documentation and believe that 25% devices has screen of size 640x960 px or I should change my graphics to the 720p screen size ?

Comment: I'm afraid you are totally confused.  Nowhere does is say that XHDPI = 640x960 px, and it would be wrong if it did.  Please read the documentation again and be sure to understand the difference between px and dip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you develop only for phones and tablets for you is unnecessary you may not use xhdpi folder for your resources. If you want that your app works fine on modern devices such as Galaxy Nexus, Nuxus 4, etc you should support xhdpi screens.

```
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp (hdpi)
xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp (xhdpi)
```